# Drop all the rows having more than 5% NULL values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I checked all the columns with more than 5% NULL values. And now I want to drop all the rows for such columns

code:

```
movies = movies.drop(movies[movies.isnull().sum(axis = 'index')/len(movies)*100 > 5],inplace = True)

print(movies)
```

I am not able to get the expected output.

Comment: do you want to remove rows that have more than 5% of null values, or remove
 columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `thresh`

```
df = df.dropna(axis=1 ,thresh = int(len(df)*0.95))
```